# Accessibility services belonging to different apps using the same library

Tags: android, kotlin, service, android-library, accessibilityservice

I am working on a library that includes an accessibility service, which is declared in the manifest. However, I have encountered a problem when multiple apps that use my library are installed on the same device. In this scenario, the accessibility service appears twice in the device settings.

While it is expected for the service to show up twice, the issue arises when I need to differentiate between the services and determine which service belongs to which app.

I would greatly appreciate any guidance or suggestions on how to tackle this problem. Is there a way to uniquely identify or label the accessibility services to associate them with the respective apps?